# NullPointer when playing sound on Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javasound

I'm getting an error when trying to play sound. I'm getting a null pointer exception for some reason. The location and file I'm using both exsist, and when outputting the file string I do get the correct path to the file. The nullpointer is on the .open line. What am I doing wrong?

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Sound {
    Clip background;

    public void init() {

    try {
        String file = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\Sounds\\Pacman_Opening.wav";
        System.out.println(file);
        background = AudioSystem.getClip();
        background.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(file)));
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public void playBG() {
        background.start();
    }
    public void stopBG() {
        background.stop();
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sound s = new Sound();
        s.init();
        s.playBG();
    }

}
```

This is the error (the first line is the location):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at main.Sound.init(Sound.java:21)
    at main.Sound.main(Sound.java:42)
```

Comment: I've edited your title for you - feel free to improve it further.

Comment: You went the dark way. "wy das tis no wok" would have been way better.

Comment: @Widor My bad, forgot to change that title, that was just a temp title, just missed changing it. What a terrible mistake, thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class.getResource()` doesn't take a *filename* - it takes a *resource* name.

Why don't you just create a `File` instead and pass that to `getAudioInputStream`?

```
// TODO: Avoid backslashes in file constructor calls; there are other ways
// of creating relative paths
File file = new File("Sounds\\Pacman_Opening.wav");
...
background.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work for me. When would it be ideal to use the getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: @Fogest: When you want the absolute path for some reason. If you *give* `File` a relative path, it will create one relative to the current working directory, which is all you want, it seems...